# Зависает форма при использовании отдельного потока

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Использую C#. Создаю отдельный поток и в нем инициализирую COM-объект для загрузки данных из сети. Не могу понять, почему зависает форма на время загрузки данных. Пробовал в потоке делать бесконечные циклы типа while и for, с ними проходит все хорошо.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Thread thread = new Thread(LoadTP);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
}

public void LoadTP()
{
       MC.Class Test = new MC.Class(); // MC.Class это DLL (COM) написанная на VB5
       Test.LoadData();
}
```

Comment: А [BackgroundWorker][1] не канает?


  [1]: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Хм. А если в `LoadTP` только большой `Sleep`, работает нормально?

Comment: Я думаю проблема в том, что операция в новом потоке загружает CPU на 100%, что и вызывает зависание.

Comment: BackgroundWorker ведет себя точно так же. Я проверял загрузку CPU, она не превышает 15%. При использовании Thread.Sleep все нормально. Возможно С# как-то криво работает с некоторыми DLL?